# How to update an input text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, textbox, button

I have this simple code that speaks for itself.

```
<script language='javascript"> 
    function check() {} 
</script> 
<div id="a">input type="text" name="b"> 
<input type="button" onClick=" check(); ">
```

All I want is that when I press the button, the text field gets a value updated to it.

I tried using `b.value=" C "` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: maybe, if nothing else is working, try changing the function name from "check()" to something else (e.g. "inputCheckFunction()"). Maybe the function name is bumping into some already used name by your browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript"> 
     function check() {
          document.getElementById('txtField').value='new value here'
     } 
</script>

<input id="txtField" type="text" name="b"> <input type="button" onClick=" check(); ">
```

This will do. I gave it an ID, and used getElementById('txtField') using the id, and updated it's value.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking that giving a form input a name attribute makes it addressable as though it were a global variable. It doesn't. There is a syntax for that, and you would have to use something like:

```
document.forms[0].b.value = "C";
```

in order to get to address it successfully. You *are* putting your form elements inside a form, aren't you?

Do it that way, or use an ID along with the getElementById method, as mplacona suggests.